# arbitrage and exchange rate: Find x if $(1-t_c)*S_f*(1-t_c)*(\frac{1}{S_f+x})<1$

Tags: finance

Okay, so I need help with this math problem. The professor said the answer is  $x=.000307785$

I need to find x if:
$$(1-t_c)*S_f*(1-t_c)*(\frac{1}{S_f+x})<1$$

$t_c=.02\% $ and $S_f=1.3000$

The answer I am getting is $x>-0.000519948$ if I change $0.2% into a decimal and not a percentage.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Well, assuming $S_f+x$ is positive this just comes to $x>S_f\left((1-t_c)^2-1\right)$.  Clearly, you need more information to produce a numerical value.

Comment: @lulu edited it. tc and Sf is known. sorry for the misinformation

Comment: Well, with that data I get the same value you get.  Nor do I get the official answer by any obvious re-interpretation of the data.  Are you sure you have transcribed the problem properly?  It is odd to have two factors of $(1-t_c)$, for example.